# es6 declaring an function with brackets

Tags: javascript

I want to declare the following function with the short synthax, but I alwys get back a mistake, saying ***"VM831:9 Uncaught TypeError: Person is not a constructor(…)"*** Do I need to write function?

```
var Person = () => {
 this.age = 0;

 this.set = () => {
    this.age++; 
   }
 }

 var p = new Person();
```

Comment: yep, arrow functions cannot be constructors. Better yet, use classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions use "lexical" `this`, i.e. they always inherit the `this` from the current scope rather than the one created by the `new` operator.

They therefore cannot be used as constructors.

Answer (score 1):

A function cannot have constructor. So use ES6 class instead.

```
class Person {
     constructor(age) {
         this.age = age;
     }
}
```